# Quel sont les mots d'argot ou familiers utilisés pour l'euro ?

Tags: argot, économie

Pour ma part je n'ai jamais entendu les correspondances en euros mentionnées sur http://projetbabel.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=274 .

Comment dites-vous "un euro" en argot : un *neuneu* ? je l'ai proposé à quelques commerçants sans résultat.

Cent balles (représentant des francs) ne correspondent pas au même pouvoir d'achat si l'on parle d'euros : 656 % d'écart.

Quel est l'argot pour l'euro que :

- vous avez entendu,
- vous avez lu,

...  et qui vous semble accepté par tous ?

Comment: À lire sur le site du journal *Les Échos* : [*Vivement l'argot de l'euro*](http://www.lesechos.fr/15/03/2005/LesEchos/19371-221-ECH_vivement-l-argot-de-l-euro.htm).

Answer (score 7):

Effectivement, on voit parfois - plus souvent en ligne sur des forums - l'argot "roro" pour parler des euros. Je ne l'ai jamais entendu et je pense que la facilité de prononciation toute relative y est pour quelque chose. Plus rarement, j'ai entendu "eu" (prononcé comme "oeufs", comme dans "50 eu").

En revanche, j'entends souvent "balles", "boules" ("300 balles, 50 boules"), "ronds" ("t'as des ronds ?").

À mon sens, on comprend que ce n'est pas spécifique à l'euro. En Francs, on utilisait déjà ces termes. Selon le contexte, "briques", "patates" pouvaient aussi se présenter.

Edit : j'en oublie "les pièces rouges", un argot pour désigner les pièces de 1, 2 et 5 centimes d'euro, plus souvent oxydées.

Comment: _Patate_: années '90, « grosse somme », un million de centimes/dix mille francs.(A. Rey, DHLF).

Answer (score 5):

L'Euro n'est pas encore rentré tout à fait dans l'argo, même "roro" ne s'entend pas tous les jours (voire jamais) !

Par contre, "balles" et "boules" (voire "brique") commencent à se convertir des francs vers l'euro, surtout auprès des jeunes n'ayant pas grands souvenirs des francs.

Donc oui, ce n'est pas le même pouvoir d'achat mais l'expression persiste quand même.

Answer (score 1):

Le plus simple que j'ai déjà entendu c'est : « Roro »

Comment: Le seul signalé par le [dictionnaire de la zone](http://www.dictionnairedelazone.fr/traduction-glossaire-e-euro.html). Et le premier qu'avait repris la presse. [*Pour 100 briques combien de thune en roros?*](http://www.liberation.fr/culture/2001/12/31/langage-pour-100-briques-combien-de-thune-en-roros_388898), article du journal *Libération*, du 31/12/2001.

Comment: @Laure L'argot se rapportant à l'argent générique reste invariable - C'est un peu comme si cette monnaie n'appartenait pas à la francophonie qui a pourtant connut des changements écu, franc, nouveaux francs ...

Answer (score 0):

Pourtant ça existe depuis deux siècles: Une thune, qui équivaut à cinq linvé, soit cent sous, a bien une valeur d’à peu près 1 Euro. Si on fait abstraction du passage de l’ancien au nouveau franc bien sûr...

Comment: Il y a confusion avec les Francs Suisses. [Cent-sous](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sou#Suisse) c'est 5 Francs Suisses (en argot une [thune](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thune#Suisse) soit environ 4.54 EUR).  Il y a deux siècles l'euro n'était pas encore en vigueur.

Comment: La thune, le linvé et le loussem étaient utilisés au 19 eme siècle dans l’argot parisien, ou les transactions en Franc Suisse étaient assez rares... Les pièces de cinq francs étaient encore parfois appelées pièce de cent sous jusqu’à la moitié du XXeme siècle. Si on rapporte son cours par rapport au Franc, (des années 90), une thune correspond donc à peu près à un Euro.

Comment: Thune est employé **de nos jours** pour parler de 5 Francs Suisses. Je n'ai jamais rencontré thune comme argot pour « euro » donc j'aimerais bien une référence, une citation.... car  la question demande un terme d'argot pour l'euro, l'équivalence en valeur avec le franc ou une autre monnaie n'a rien à voir.